# Locking a specific pattern on Screen Keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

We work on live chat to sell online, and to accept the chat that is being transferred we have to press CTRL+ALT+J , Is there are way to use screen keyboard to lock that patter down and be the first one to accept the incoming chat

Comment: You want those keys to always be pressed?

Comment: Do you *need* to use the screen keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.autoitscript.com/site/

You could use an AutoIt script like this:

```
HotKeySet("{ESC}","Quit")

While 1
    Send("{CTRLDOWN}{ALTDOWN}j")
    Send("{CTRLUP}{ALTUP}")
    Sleep(500)
WEnd


Func Quit()
    Send("{CTRLUP}{ALTUP}")
    Exit
EndFunc
```

Every half a second it presses that keycombination, so when Genesys shows an incoming call you'll always be the first to join it. Pressing the Escape button will stop the script. Your co-workers will dislike you though.